# ASN.1 to DER encoding

Tags: rsa, asn.1, der

I'm trying to generate RSA public key I have ASN.1 code I need to encode with DER

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
modulus           INTEGER,  7120255303029382831
publicExponent    INTEGER   4242026487
}
My DER code 30 10 08 02 62 D0 3A 79 2F 28 5E AF 02 04 FC D8 2F F7
```

My DER code is wrong please help me how can I write as correctly

Comment: Perhaps you can explain how you arrived at your encoding?

Comment: Just FYI, encoded value is almost ok except it has missing leading `00` in front of `FC D8 2F F7`. Since the most significant bit of integer is 1 it is treated as negative integer (using two-complement notation), you have to add extra zero byte in front to make it positive like it is in your schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can/should use a tool to do that.

https://asn1.io/asn1playground/

Compile your spec

[image: Compile your specification]

Encode a value

[image: Decode a value]

Read the result

[image: Read the result]